# Sandbox or safely execute eval

Tags: javascript, security, sandbox

In a large project of mine, I've run into a situation where a client might need to run evaluated JavaScript code. I know, it makes me cringe too. One option is to manually parse it, but for future flexibility, I would like to evaluate the code safely.

Everything I've seen and researched says, NO. Ah, the nay-sayers.

This is my attempt to sandbox the eval:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/senica/Pd6Nu/)

Can you shoot holes in it and try and break it? I should wrap it in a try so it doesn't throw ugly errors, but beyond that, tell me where I have gone awry.

```
/***************************************
 * Senica Gonzalez (senica@gmail.com)
 * This is an attempt to sandbox an eval
 * in javascript using an iframe.
 * Test it and let me know if you
 * can break it.
 ***************************************/

window.addEventListener("message", function(event){
    $('#result').text(event.data.eval);
    console.log(event.data.scope1);
    console.log(event.data.scope2);
}, false);

test = 'do I exist in the window?';

var input = $('[name=toeval]');
input.on('change', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    var code = btoa('<html>\
        <head><\/head>\
        <body>\
            <' + 'script>\
                var party_size = 10;\
                window.parent.postMessage({\
                    eval: eval('+val+'),\
                }, "*");\
            <\/script' + '>\
        <\/body>\
    <\/html>');
    var frame = $('<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" src="data:text/html;base64,'+code+'"></iframe>');
    var sandbox = $('#sandbox');
    sandbox.html(frame);
});
```

I have been unsuccessful at accessing the parent document variables, or being able to do anything obnoxious other than to my self within the sandbox.

Comment: The character sequence `"</script>"` should be escaped using `"<\/script>"` (and so should all other closing tags in string literals), the way you have it does nothing useful.

Comment: You didn't run it. It works as is. If you escape them, then it won't run as a script, which it needs to.

Comment: `allow-same-origin` is all the security hole you need, isn't it? Also what about browsers that don't understand the `sandbox` attribute?

Comment: @SenicaGonzalez—it runs because browsers ignore the script tag that should close the element (test it in an [*HTML validator*](http://validator.w3.org/)). Quoting the closing `/` as suggested certainly does not stop the inserted script from running. See [*Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write).

Comment: @Bergi it runs without the allow-same-origin method. Yes, browsers that do not recognize sandbox is certainly an issue.

Comment: Read - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681460/making-a-same-domain-iframe-secure , also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653809/making-webworkers-a-safe-environment and of course - check out "Secure ECMAScript"

Comment: @Bergi Yes, that's true. That combined with `allow-scripts` would make it pretty easy to just reach out and remove the `sandbox` attribute. The fiddle has only `allow-scripts` and not `allow-same-origin`.

Comment: Are you storing what they enter and serving it to others? If not, and they're only executing the code they enter, then it poses no threat to anyone but themselves.

Comment: By the way, why do you need base64 there? I guess you can do something like data:text/html,(html-code). Just escape it.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, I can poke a few holes in this.

Firstly, your `eval()` isn't actually doing much of anything here. From the perspective of the parser running the script, that line looks like this:

```
eval(party_size < 5)
```

This means that `party_size < 5` is evaluated to `false` *before* it is passed to the `eval()` function. `eval()` then just spits this value right back out.

Some consequences of this:

- It will fail to act as expected if the expression evaluates to a string value. For example, if you put `"a" + "b"` into your textbox, this will fail with the error `ReferenceError: ab is not defined`, because the JS engine will be trying to evaluate `eval("ab")`.
- It will fail if the code is anything other than a single expression. So entering this into the textbox: `var a = 2; a;` fails with a syntax error, even though this is a perfectly legitimate thing to pass to `eval()`.

So let's assume that was just a silly oversight and you meant to do this:

```
eval: eval("'+val+'"),\
```

Well, this will succeed in actually executing chunks of code, until that code contains a quotation mark:

```
eval("var a = "a"; a + "b"");
```

at which point it will be broken again.



Now let's imagine you decided to get around this by changing this line to:

```
eval: eval("' + val.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '"),\
```

Now you can be pretty confident that the code will run (in most cases) and that all you need to worry about at this point is malicious code (haha).

In terms of malicious code, the attacker could execute something resource intensive that hogs the CPU and RAM:

```
var a = []; while(true) { a.push(new Date()); console.log("gotcha!"); }
```

Or they might choose to carry out a [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)-like attack:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("post", "https://www.mybank.com/transferMoney");
x.send("amount=10000&toAccount=34567890");
```

So keeping the host DOM safe is really not the only thing to worry about. There are any other number of malicious things an attacker can carry out if they're able to run code on someone's machine.

Given the above, I would stick with the assertion that `eval` is evil, and it's not going to be easy to find a "safe" way to execute untrusted code.

Comment: This is incorrect. You cannot make that XMLHttpRequest unless you add allow-same-origin to the sandbox attribute. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486461/iframe-sandbox-attribute-is-blocking-ajax-calls

Answer (score 6):

There is a safe and sandboxed way to execute JavaScript code without using eval, is to have a JavaScript interpreter written in JavaScript itself. There is an implementation by Neil Fraser at Google called JS-Interpreter, I am using it and it is a good and simple solution, this is the [repo in Github](https://github.com/NeilFraser/JS-Interpreter). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for Node.js and the browser is:

```
var globalScope = global ? global : window // node.js and browser
var globals = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(globalScope)

module.exports = function makeSafeEval (include) {
  var clearGlobals = ''
  for (var i = 0, len = globals.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (include && include.indexOf(globals[i]) === -1 || !include) {
      clearGlobals += 'var ' + globals[i] + ' = undefined;'
    }
  }
  return function (operation) {
    var globals = undefined // out of scope for operation
    return eval('(function () {' + clearGlobals + ';return ' + operation.replace('this', '_this') + '})()')
  }
}

var safeEval = makeSafeEval()
safeEval('this') // undefined
safeEval('window') // undefined
```

This not prevents you from malicius code that consumes the memory and CPU. This protection would be achieved by executing the above code in a worker and send messages in an interval, if blocked you can terminate it. On browser you can use a Webworker and in node a Cluster Worker. The above code is avalaible as npm module as cross-safe-eval and the code in my [Github](https://github.com/carloslfu/cross-safe-eval), hope it helps someone.

Comment: This is NOT a safe solution!! It's possible to prevent the function which clears globals from running (in a mysql-injection-like fashion). If `operation` is set to: `0; }); (function() { console.log('Now I can do anything!!'); var thiis = eval('th' + 'is');` then a malicious user can run any code they like, and even get a reference to `this`. This is because the global-clearing code is parsed into a function which is never called.